# echo $HADOOP_HOME is blank

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop but when i am using   `echo $HADOOP_HOME`    .its showing blank.please help how to check hadoop location.

Answer (score 1):

This may occur due to following reasons:

1. You are not logging into your user that you have created for Hadoop.
2. You have not specified the path for Hadoop home path all-together.
3. The Variable that you are using for storing hadoop home has a different name. for example : HADOOP_PREFIX.

Whatever the case is you can check your .profile or .bashrc file where you have specified HADOOP_HOME path.

This can be done by both Terminal or GUI:

I. By Terminal

1. Login in into your hadoop user by using $su - hduser (note: in my case user name is hduser)
2. Then open .profile file by using $vi .profile
3. get down to the bottom of the file and you will see your home path for hadoop.

alternatively,

2. open .bashrc file by using $sudo gedit .bashrc
3. scroll down to bottom and check your hadoop home path there.

II. By GUI

1. goto /home in your linux system.
2. there you will find user folder for hadoop in my case it was hduser.
3. there you will find .bashrc and .profile file. open them and confirm your path for hadoop home.